# Understanding a possible consequence of Doob's martingale theorem

Tags: convergence-divergence, martingales

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a number sequence that converges to a limit $a\in\mathbb{R}$, and fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists some integer $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq m$ it holds that $|a_n-a_m|<\varepsilon$.

Now let $(\Omega,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, and let $\{X_n\}$ be a bounded, non-negative martingale. Thus, it converges a.s to a finite random variable $X_\infty$.
By definition, this means that with probability 1, $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n=X_\infty$.

I'm trying to translate the Cauchy-like logic from number sequences to converging martingales. Intuitively, one (me) might say immediately that, fixing $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some integer $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq m$, $|X_n-X_m|< \varepsilon$.

1. Is that $m$ then a random variable itself?
2. If so, it is not necessarily a stopping time. What can one say on $X_m$ then? Can I define it as a random variable as well?

Thanks in advance for all types of comments and inputs!

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. $X_m$ is a random variable.

Comment: Hey Kurt - how do you KNOW that $m$ is a random variable? Was trying to show it be definition and failed.

Comment: Can you make an attempt to formalize that $X_n$ converges with probability one? Start this with "For $\mathbb P$-almost all $\omega\in\Omega$ ...".